# Flutter: AndroidManifest cannot find @xml resource

Tags: flutter, resources, android-manifest, android-resources

I have created a flutter app for which I want to implement a home screen widget. For a first try, I am following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@ashishgarg1998/how-to-create-home-screen-app-widgets-in-flutter-ce3458f3638e

After copying the code snippets, the following exception is thrown on build:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
Android resource linking failed
     /Users/me/Documents/MyApp/myapp/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:41:13-42:55: AAPT: error: resource xml/widget_info (aka de.myapp.myapp:xml/widget_info) not found.
```

The error-causing code within the AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
<receiver android:name="AppWidgetProvider" >
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data 
         android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
         android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

Apparently, the widget_info.xml file cannot be located. I have tried to just use the full file path but the compiler will only let me use the @xml/... notation. How can I fix this? Sidenote: I don't have any Android/Kotlin experience, only Flutter.

Below, you can see my file structure:
[image: File Structure]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found the solution myself by now. The AndroidManifest.xml file is looking for the @xml resource in the

```
android/app/src/main/res
```

folder and not the

```
android/app/res
```

folder as the tutorial suggests. So moving the widget_info.xml file did the trick.